# check if request is ssl in an haproxy offload ssl environment

Tags: php, haproxy

I have a pound server with ssl offload in front of a haproxy.

How can I check in my php code if the request has been done with ssl if I have offload ssl and the ssl doesn't hit the web server?

Maybe put some header tag or something in haproxy to the ssl request so I can check this header in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up is to add the header in Pound configuration and check this header in the code:

```
AddHeader "X-Pound: SSL"
```

Answer (score 1):

From [HAProxy and SSL](http://blog.exceliance.fr/haproxy/haproxy-and-ssl/)

> The configuration directive below must be inserted in the Frontend configuration. It tells HAProxy to add a header named X-SSL which contains the information about the type of frontend connection:

```
http-request set-header X-SSL %[ssl_fc]
```

This should then show up in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL']`.

Comment: But this is when haproxy manage the ssl connection and needs vers. 1.5 of haproxy. I'm using 1.3 with pound server in front that do the ssl offload.

Comment: @barmar
it's not the accepted answer but solved my problem with newer version of haproxy